# How to drag a view out of the workbench in RCP app?

Tags: view, eclipse-rcp, detach

I am trying to figure out how to detach a view from the main app. From what I can tell this is a supported feature in the RCP framework but I have not seen how to enable/disable the feature. Is there a property I can set somewhere in the View Hierarchy to enable this?

Comment: Also does anyone know when this feature was supported? Perhaps I am not using the right eclipse pulg-ins.

Answer (score 0):

Just drag the view by its title tab out of the eclipse window, e.g. to a second screen, or make the eclipe window not beeing full sized.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the problem is that in my app I will drag the view out of the app and looks as though it will detach it but nothing happens. The view does not move at all.

Comment: @BitwiseDK possibly the programmatic approach in this [forum post](http://www.java-forum.org/plattformprogrammierung/115476-detached-view-beim-starten-rcps.html) help you further